# How do I get user inputs into an array list when there is an aggregate class involved?

Tags: java

I have two classes, treatments and booking, Ive applied aggregation to them. In the main driver class the user has to be able to add new treatments so that information will all be saved into an array list. I get an error when i try to get it to insert the user input into the array. I would appreciate it if someone told me what I was doing wrong.

Treatments class

```
public class treatment {
    
    String treatment_type;
    String treatment_procedure;
    // aggregated
    booking booking;
    
    
    
    treatment( String treatment_type, String treatment_procedure, booking bookings ){
        
        this.treatment_type = treatment_type;
        this.treatment_procedure = treatment_procedure;
        this.booking = bookings;
        
        
    }
}
```

Bookings class

```
public class booking {
    
    String patientname;
    String doctorname;
    String date;
    String time;
    
    public booking (String p, String d, String da, String t) {
        
        this.patientname = p;
        this.doctorname = d;
        this.date = da;
        this.time = t;
        
    }
}
```

Driver class

```
 public static void treatments(){
                                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please provide treatment information");
                System.out.println("Enter the Patient's name :");
                String pname = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the doctors name :");
                String dname = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the date of the appointment :");
                String date = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter your time of appointment :");
                String time = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the type of treatment :");
                String treattype = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the specifics of the procedure :");
                String specifics = sc.next();
                                
                treatment newtreatment = new treatment(pname,dname,date, time, treattype, specifics);
                treatmentlist.add(newtreatment);
                System.out.println("The dentist has been registered Successfully");
                                           
                        }
```

The line that is underlines in red is

```
treatment newtreatment = new treatment(pname,dname,date, time, treattype, specifics);
```

The error message says the following
required: String,String,booking
found: String,String,String,String,String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I know the length isnt right so to test it I minimized it to just 3 values to see if the error would go off but one was still underlined saying the following
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to booking

Anybody got any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for the `treatment` class takes two `String` arguments and a `booking` argument.

```
treatment( String treatment_type, String treatment_procedure, booking bookings ){
```

When you use it, you call it with six `String` arguments.

```
new treatment(pname,dname,date, time, treattype, specifics);
```

Now, your `booking` class' constructor takes four `String` arguments, so I suspect you meant to use four of the `String` arguments to construct a `booking` object that you'd pass as an argument to the `treatment` constructor.

Something like:

```
new treatment(treattype, specifics, new booking(pname, dname, date, time));
```

Comment: Yessss that solved my issue, it works fine now. Thank you for your help.